# small trouble in NSUserDefault with strings

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays, nsuserdefaults

when I save my array every thing is good

```
NSMutableArray *savestring = news;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savestring"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

the `NSLog` here is a titles, around 10 titles (simple from the output):

```
2013-08-19 11:23:13.556 Dr.Saleh[4282:1303] saveString= (
    "Sumou Real Estate Company Won The Award of the World Confederation of Business"
)
2013-08-19 11:23:13.558 Dr.Saleh[4282:1303] saveString= (
    "Biggest  indoor Mapping Projection event"
)
2013-08-19 11:23:13.559 Dr.Saleh[4282:1303] saveString= (
    "Sumou Real Estate launches"
)
```

.......etc

then when i load the strings it take the last string only this is the loading code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"savestring"];
[defaults setValue:loadstring forKey:@"savestring"];
news = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"savestring"];
```

the `NSLog` of news give my only the last string save in savestring where is my mistake

//==========================================================================//

I solve my problem with changing this code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savestring"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

and make it like that

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[[NSUserDefaults   standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"savestring"] arrayByAddingObject:news]     forKey:@"savestring"];
```

Comment: What is news in above code?

Comment: what does "news" contains?

Comment: I want it to save the titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "news" is of type array with the title objects is what you refer for!!!,

```
NSMutableArray *savestring =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:news];
//news is an array which has the titles..
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savestring"];
```

OR

You can directly save it without assigning it to savestring...

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:news forKey:@"savestring"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: how about load the strings and save it in *news?

Comment: how ur loading the strings and saving it in news?

Comment: I want to save all of the titles in news

Comment: NSMutableArray *news=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"titel1",@"title2",@"title3",nil];

Comment: Ok...how ur adding those dynamic title into the array?...when generated,add the title object to your array like this...[news addObject:title1]; etc

Comment: first I save the titles with NSUserDefault (savestring)
second I load the titles (loadstring)
finally :
    news = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"savestring"];

Comment: @property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *news;

Comment: am asking about the 1st part...NSMutableArray *savestring = news;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savestring"];
[defaults synchronize];
==>forget the 1st part...before doing this part,how ur storing the titles into the news?

Comment: news=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:loadstring,nil];  :(

Comment: what is loadstring?...datatype?

Comment: do one thing..just paste the whole code here http://pastebin.com...and give me the link